# Optimizing nested query to JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-optimization

I have below query in a `function` which returns `count` -

```
 SELECT @CommentCount  = COUNT(1)               
 FROM cs_posts              
 WHERE PostLevel IN (2,3) AND IsApproved=1  AND ThreadId=(SELECT ThreadId FROM Cs_Posts WHERE PostId=@PostID)          

 RETURN @CommentCount
```

And to `improve the performance` i need to `optimize` this.

Further i have used this `function in SP`, where this function is called `36` times [see below] -

```
INSERT INTO @TempPostIds (RowID,PostID)                                           
SELECT TOP 36                      
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN @sortBy  ='comments' THEN ISNULL(dbo.GetCommentCountForPost(CP.PostID),0) END DESC, <---here the function is called
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'views' THEN IsNull(MAVC.ViewCount,CP.TotalViews) END DESC,
CASE WHEN @sortBy='date' THEN CP.PostDate END DESC),         
CP.PostID

 from CS_Posts as CP with (nolock)                                          
 inner join NewsletterDetails AD  (nolock ) on CP.PostID = AD.PostID                                          
 Inner Join cs_Threads CT (NOLOCK) on CP.ThreadID = CT.ThreadID                                          
 Inner Join MapNewsletterPosts MM (NOLOCK)on MM.PostID = AD.PostId                                          
 Inner Join NewsLetter NW (NOLOCK) ON NW.ID = MM.ID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PostViewCount MAVC (NOLOCK) ON CP.PostID = MAVC.PostID                                          
 WHERE                                          
 CP.isapproved =1                                          
 AND CP.PostStatus = 7                                           
 AND CP.SectionID in(95,199)  
 AND AD.IncludeInArticles=1                                           
 AND AD.NewsletterDate <= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Please help and suggest.

Comment: Not much we can do without a query plan.

Comment: Use a TVF, not a Scalar function.

Comment: Please post DDL script for your table, all the indexes you defined and the execution plan

Comment: Using `EXISTS` might be better on your Subquery too.

Comment: Sight detour....https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your function correctly (especially without the table structure), but I believe your nested query is not needed:

```
SELECT @CommentCount  = COUNT(1)               
FROM cs_posts              
WHERE PostLevel IN (2,3) AND IsApproved=1  AND PostId=@PostID
RETURN @CommentCount
```

Good luck!

Comment: That's not likely. You are selecting one post only. The original query seems to select all posts of the same thread as the given post.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

For this query:

```
SELECT @CommentCount  = COUNT(1)               
FROM cs_posts              
WHERE PostLevel IN (2, 3) AND
      IsApproved = 1  AND
      ThreadId = (SELECT p2.ThreadId FROM Cs_Posts p2 WHERE p2.PostId = @PostID);
```

You want indexes on `cs_posts(PostId, ThreadId)` and `cs_posts(IsApproved, PostLevel, ThreadId)`.

Comment: one more, can we shorten the `CASE` statements as well from above `SP`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a Scalar Function, use a TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCommentCountForPost_tvf (@PostID int) RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS CommentCount
    FROM cs_posts c
    WHERE c.PostLevel IN (2,3)
      AND c.IsApproved = 1
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Cs_Posts e WHERE e.PostId = @PostID AND e.ThreadId = c.ThreadId);
```

Then, in your `SELECT` change `ISNULL(dbo.GetCommentCountForPost(CP.PostID),0)` to `ISNULL(GCC.CommentCount,0)` and add the following to your `FROM`:

```
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetCommentCountForPost_tvf(CP.PostID) GCC
```

Comment: one more, can we shorten the `CASE` statements as well from above `SP`

Comment: @PPB not sure what you mean by "shorten them". Those `CASE` expressions can't get any shorter, considering you want them in separate evaluations and they have no `ELSE`.

Comment: I've applied `CROSS APPLY' since then it gets executed when sort is 'Views' and 'date' ,any suggestion?

Comment: @PPB I'm afraid that statement doesn't make any sense. Can you try to reword it?

Comment: Before when there was no `CROSS APPLY` the SP was executing within a second for both sorts `Date` and `Views`, but now it takes time. why?